# Inject the code for at a time concurrent users can open the app

Tags: gatling

I am working in [Gatling](http://gatling.io/). I first recorded the app and generated a [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/) file. Then I run the code using gatling.sh.

Here is the code that hits the application for 5 users for diiferent time period .

```
setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(5))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

I want to know the code for 10 concurrent users to open the app on the same time.

I want to check my app to find out how many concurrent users can open the app on the same time without any crashes. Do I need to allocate memory for my server?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to find out how many concurrent users your app can take is to change the number of concurrent users (`atOnceUsers()`) the test runs.

Ten concurrent users is `atOnceUsers(10)`

Just keep increasing the number of concurrent users until something fails.

You do not need to allocate memory for your server: you need to note that the app fails with `x` concurrent users on a server with memory of `y`. If your environment isn't a mirror of production, you can look at different server variables or use virtual machines where you can easily change the memory available to change the memory and see how well the app scales.

I strongly recommend you work your way through several basic coding tutorials, because you have asked many questions that can be answered with basic coding knowledge. You will be less confused if you understand basic code.

Comment: I want to know the 10 concurrent users on the same time 

And I tried this code setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(10))).protocols(httpProtocol)  . 


This will ge the  different time period for 10 conurrent users.